# made a cookie in php, now trying to update it in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

```
echo  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "function del_cookie()";
echo "{";
echo "document.cookie = logged_amount + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';";
echo "}";

echo "</script>";

echo "<form action=logout.php name=Logout>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=\"Log Out\"> | <a href='./archive.php'>View History</a> | <a href='#' onclick='del_cookie'>Mark as read</a><form>";


setcookie("logged_amount", $x, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

When I try to click "Mark as read" it doesn't really work. Am I missing something? Also if I can I'd really like to update the cookie with the `$x` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up with javascript.

```
if (isset($_GET['markread'])) {
    if ($_GET['markread'] == 1) {
        setcookie("logged_amount", $x, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=view.php'>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.cookie =  logged_amount +
                  ^             ^
```

You didn't surround the `logged_amount` with quotes, so Javascript's seeing it as an (undefined) variable. So you're trying to set a cookie with a blank name. Try

```
document.cookie = 'logged_amount' + ...
```

instead.

Comment: I added the single quotes inside and it still didn't change anything. Something in my code is wrong.  Is there anyway I can update the cookie in PHP by clicking an url?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** `setcookie()` in PHP doesn't work after the headers are sent. In other words, you need to place `setcookie()` before you `echo` out anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

to read cookies in jquery use the:

```
$.cookie('cookie_name')
```

and to set it use:

```
$.cookie('cookie_name','cookie_val')
```